# Como saber que versión de ODAC tengo? como saber la versión de ODAC que necesito?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

estoy en un dilema que quisiera que me colaboren, en mi equipo de desarrollo tengo un sistema desarrollado con VS2015 con EF6 contra Oracle 10g, ahora bien el mismo sistema no funciona en equipos de producción, llegue a la conclusión de que es por el ODAC (*Oracle Data Access Components*) que no es el mismo en los dos equipos, tengo 3 preguntas en las cuales quisiera que me colaboren:

1. Como saber que versión de ODAC tengo instalado en cada equipo???
2. Como saber que versión de ODAC necesita mi proyecto para ejecutarse??
3. Si instalo un ODAC 12 sobre uno que tiene un 11 o inferior, funcionan los dos paralelamente o el 12 sobreescribiria al mas antioguo??

Gracias por su ayuda. Saludos.